# journalctl gets corrupted

Tags: system-installation

When I type: sudo journalctl --verify

I always get: *Data object's entry array not sorted

File corruption detected at* by some of my logs.

[Screenshot from terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIMyz.png)

How can I know what causes this in Ubuntu? I have Pop_Os! installation on my other drive with much larger log file and it never gets corrupted. I have tested my disk fdisc and it shows no errors. I have also installed Ubuntu in other partition and same corruption starts there too after a while.

Comment: Pop!_OS is off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

It is not nice to see these corruptions in log files. In principle, the corrupt files [can be rewritten](https://systemd-devel.freedesktop.narkive.com/NZtfS8dv/journal-repair), but according to a Redhat software engineer, for now, we best simply ignore these corruptions rather than clean them up. [Quote](https://systemd-devel.freedesktop.narkive.com/NZtfS8dv/journal-repair):

> There isn't really any point in deleting them. journalctl salvages
> automatically everything it can when reading them. Since the files are
> mostly append-only the corruptions usually only affect half-written
> entries at the end, and hence all earlier once should just work.
>
> I am pretty sure we simply need to document this in more detail, and
> clarify that corrupted journal files are nothing to act on, and the
> journalctl recovers what it can on read, implicitly, with no fsck-like
> tool being necessary, and without requiring people to manually delete
> anything.